# How can I edit my JVM section under my Project template in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, jvm

I am trying to learn Kotlin from this book: **Kotlin Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide, 2nd Edition**

I have downloaded the most recent version of IntelliJ Idea. The book wants me to do this step for creating my first Kotlin project:

[creating new Kotlin Project with Application JVM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wFLG.png)

On my new version of IntelliJ Idea I see this: (Which is not like the book)

[My version of IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUZTi.png)

Is there a way to edit my settings so Application shows up under my JVM section?

Answer (score 0):

Choose New Project | Kotlin on the Welcome Screen:

[image: New Kotlin Project]